# Get all points from multiline in shapefile using C# and GDAL

Tags: gdal, c#

I'm trying to read a shapefile and draw it using DirectX and GDAL library. So first I will read the shapefile and get a list of all the points in the shapefile. It works with linestring using `GetPoint()`.

```
var polylines = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<Point3D>>();
Feature feat;
while ((feat = layer.GetNextFeature()) != null) {
    var geom = feat.GetGeometryRef();
    var points = new List<Point3D>();
    for (var i = 0; i < geom.GetPointCount(); i++)
        {   
            double[] geopoint = {0, 0, 0};
            geom.GetPoint(i, geopoint);
            points.Add(new Point3D(geopoint[0], geopoint[1], geopoint[2]));
        }

    polylines.TryAdd(feat.GetFID().ToString(), points);
    feat.Dispose();
}
```

But when the geometry is `MultiLineString` then `GetPoint()`, it always returns `0`. Does anyone know if there is a way to unpack `MultilLineString` to `LineString` or read `MultiLineString` using GDAL?

Answer (score 2):

So, after digging around. I finally found a way to unpack multilinestring.

```
var polylines = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<Point3D>>();
Feature feat;
while ((feat = layer.GetNextFeature()) != null) {
    var geom = feat.GetGeometryRef();
    var points = new List<Point3D>();
    if (geom.GetGeometryCount() > 0) //Check to see if the geometry is multigeometry
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < geom.GetGeometryCount(); i++)
        {
           var line = geom.GetGeometryRef(i);

           //Get points using the code I post before
         }
    }

    polylines.TryAdd(feat.GetFID().ToString(), points);
    feat.Dispose();
}
```

This should also work with multipolygons.